# Understanding how to set up g(f(x)) comparatively to f(g(x))

Tags: derivatives

The question reads:

> Given the following functions: $f(x)=\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=x^{7}+1$, find:
>
> - **a:** $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = ?$
> - **b:** $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} g(f(x)) = ?$

For **(a)**, I obtained: $\cos x(x^7+1) \longrightarrow$ derivative $-\sin(x^7+1)(7x) \longrightarrow -7x \sin(x^7+1)$.

However, for **(b)** I am having a problem understanding.

Am I suppose to set it up as $x^{7}+1(\cos x)$ or $\cos^{7}+1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part b, it says your *f(x)* needs to be on the inside and *g(x)* needs to be on the outside.

Your second answer is right, because you would then replace the *x* with cos, so you would get cos^7 +1

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, for part (b), you have  $f(x)=\cos(x)$. Thus for $g(f(x))$ you have to substitute instead of $x$  $f(x)$. So you get $g(f(x))= f(x)^7+1$

Comment: So the set up would be g(f(x))= cos(x)^7+1? Making the derivative 7cosx^6(-sinx) --> -7cosx^6sinx

Comment: Exactly, moreover, you may approach the derivative  using chain true even before substitution. So for example  $\frac{d}{dx} g(f(x))=\frac{dg}{dx} (f(x)) \times  f'(x)  $ but $\frac{dg}{dx}(x)=7x^6 $ so  $\frac{d}{dx} g(f(x))= 7(f(x))^6 \times (-\sin(x))= -7\cos(c)^6 \sin(x) $